# MySQL Update SET replace with PHP mutiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run 3 lines of the same code as seen below.I've also tried the W3Schools PHP mysqli_multi_query() Function but it gives me a syntax error and only the 1-st line of code works the `ExistingWord1`

I also read a couple of stackoverflow posts about this and this can't figure it out

```
<?php
include 'words.php';
include('../config.php');
$servername = DB_HOSTNAME;
$username = DB_USERNAME;
$password = DB_PASSWORD;
$dbname = DB_DATABASE;
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
/*UTF-8 format*/
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord1', '$ReplacerWord1') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord1%';";
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord2', '$ReplacerWord2') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord2%';";
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord3', '$ReplacerWord3') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord3%';";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Products updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

This is the full Code that i am trying to run as by itself it only runs the 1st $sql =""

and ignores the other 2

as for the variables in the REPLACE

```
$ExistingWord1 words that are in the database name
$ReplacerWord1  replaces the ExistingWord1
'%$SearchWord1%' real database names
```

**Thanks for the help guys**

Everyone in this post was really helpful i really do appriciate it.

Comment: there is not enough here for us to go on. What is the error that you're getting and what is the other code associated with running this?

Comment: Post full fragment of your code please. In lines you posted there is no mysql calls

Comment: according to the fragment provided only last `$sql` value will be executed, since you redefine same variable 3 times, only the last value stored in var `$sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the fragment provided only last `$sql` value will be executed, since you redefine same variable 3 times, only the last value stored in var `$sql`.

To fix that you can try:

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord1', '$ReplacerWord1') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord1%';";
$sql .= "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord2', '$ReplacerWord2') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord2%';";
$sql .= "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord3', '$ReplacerWord3') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord3%';";
```

**UPDATE** So now you have just debug your query and code any preffered way. For example:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord1', '$ReplacerWord1') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord1%';";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "1. Products updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
    $sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord2', '$ReplacerWord2') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord2%';";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "2. Products updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

    $sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord3', '$ReplacerWord3') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord3%';";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "3. Products updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Where i do that i get this error

Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, 'Banana', 'Cigars from the t' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

Why not just nest the `REPLACE` functions, and get it done in one fell swoop.

```
  SET t.name = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( t.name, 'fee','bah'),'fi','hum'), 'fo','bug')
```

You don't really need a WHERE clause, if you're going to be scanning the whole table anyway.

```
 WHERE t.name LIKE '%fee%'
    OR t.name LIKE '%fi%'
    OR t.name LIKE '%fo%'
```

That's only going to require one scan through the table.

But this approach only "works" if you're not "swapping" keywords, and don't have collisions. (For example, first replacing "fee" with "foo" and the replacing  "foo" with "bar"... the order the operations is important.

---

NOTES:

The `REPLACE` function replaces strings, not words. This is important if you are planning on running this against text or comments.

Code that incorporate potentially unsafe values in SQL text is vulnerable SQL Injection.

Potentially unsafe values *must* be properly escaped using e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Or, the preferred pattern is to use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

Enabling multiquery opens up a whole host more opportunities for even *nastier* SQL injection; giving the ability to slide in whole statements, like `DROP TABLE` statements. Don't enable multiquery until you are *positive* your code isn't vulnerable.

**FOLLOWUP**

Preferred pattern is to use *prepared statement* with *bind placeholders*.

I'd prefer doing the replacement with *one* scan through the table, rather than three. The `LIKE '%...'` predicates in the `WHERE` clause aren't sargable, it's gonna be a full scan anyway.

---

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(name,?,?)?,?)?,?)
         WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
            OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
            OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') ";

$sth=$conn->prepare($sql);
$sth->bind_param("sssssssss",$ExistingWord1,$ReplacerWord1
                            ,$ExistingWord2,$ReplacerWord2
                            ,$ExistingWord3,$ReplacerWord3
                            ,$SearchWord1
                            ,$SearchWord2
                            ,$SearchWord3
                );

$sth->execute();
```

---

(Add appropriate error checking around the `prepare` and `execute` calls. With PDO, we'd use try/catch/finally blocks.)

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` does not work with `mysqli`-functions. And all `mysql`-functions are removed in the upcoming PHP7.

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, exactly. I was giving an example (**"e.g"**.is "exempli gratia", meaning "for the sake of example".  It was a mistake on my part to reference mysql_ interface function. In this context, I should have referenced the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function, given that OP code is already using mysqli and given that I was recommending a preferred pattern of using *prepared statements* and *bind placeholders*. I think it's pretty clear that I wasn't advocating continued use of the deprecated `mysql` interface. My intent was to point out that OP code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way but upon reading your guys comments mainly @Alex's  comment

I changed the variables to

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord1', '$ReplacerWord1') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord1%';";
$A = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord2', '$ReplacerWord2') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord2%';";
$B = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, '$ExistingWord3', '$ReplacerWord3') WHERE name LIKE '%$SearchWord3%';";
```

And added

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Everything worked as planned";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
if ($conn->query($A) === TRUE) {

} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
if ($conn->query($B) === TRUE) {

} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: But why do *three* scans through the table, when the changes could be accomplished in just *one* scan of the table? What if this is a large table, and takes minutes (or hours) to scan. Do we really want to process that whole set multiple times? (We're not seeing the source of those PHP variables, so this code looks vulnerable to SQL Injection.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Well as i said above i am not familiar with MySQL and i have 0 ida how it works and couldn't figure out how to use it so that was my solution for the thing that i needed to do.

And the point of all this is to scan inside a coulm product_descrption for row name and find said word and change it to another.that's about it